# Npm Start Not Working in ReactJs,But My create-app was created successfully

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, create-react-app

npm ERR! Failed at the react crud@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[click here to see complete error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeQIU.png)

Comment: Can you share the complete logs?

Comment: can you provide your package.json file scripts

Comment: click the above link and see my complete error,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `C:\Windows\System32` to Path System Variable and restart your PC.